# Proof about sequence of non-negative real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

How do I do this one? I don't know how to start.

Comment: the sequence 1, -1, 1, -1, ... shows that the if direction does not hold in general

Comment: but $x_n$ are nonnegative here

Comment: @lightfish: yogesh is answering to the second part of the question about "arbitrary convergent sequence".

Comment: oh i see, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight technicality involved in proving $$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}^{2} = L^{2}\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = L$$ This assertion is valid only when $x_{n} \geq 0$ after a certain point which implies that $L \geq 0$.

Moreover we need to differentiate the case $L^{2} > 0$ and $L^{2} = 0$. If $L^{2} > 0$ then we know that $L > 0$. Now for any given $\epsilon > 0$ we have a positive integer $N$ such that $$L^{2} - \epsilon < x_{n}^{2} < L^{2} + \epsilon$$ for all $n > N$. Since $L^{2} > 0$ it is possible to choose $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 3L^{2}/4 $ so that $$\frac{L^{2}}{4} < L^{2} - \epsilon < x_{n}^{2} < L^{2} + \epsilon$$ Since $x_{n}$ is non-negative it follows by taking square roots that $x_{n} > L/2$ and hence $x_{n} + L > 3L/2$. Now we can see that $$0 \leq |x_{n} - L| = \frac{|x_{n}^{2} - L^{2}|}{|x_{n} + L|} < \frac{2}{3L}|x_{n}^{2} - L^{2}| < \frac{2\epsilon}{3L}$$ for all $n > N$. It follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = L$.

Next let $L^{2} = 0$ so that $L = 0$. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}^{2} = 0$ therefore for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have a positive integer $N$ such that $0 \leq x_{n}^{2} < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$. By taking square roots we get $0 \leq x_{n} < \sqrt{\epsilon}$ for all $n > N$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

How to start:

1. For the forward direction,  assume that $\lim x_n=L$.  Let $\epsilon>0$, and find some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we must have $|x_n^2-L^2|\le \epsilon$.
2. For the reverse direction, assume that $\lim x_n^2=L^2$.  Let $\epsilon>0$, and find some $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we must have $|x_n-L|\le \epsilon$.

Comment: well yeah, but i dont know where to go from here.

Comment: For OP: You can try to see that $|x_{n}^{2} - L^{2}| = |x_{n} + L||x_{n} - L|$ and the link between $|x_{n}^{2} - L^{2}|$ and $|x_{n} - L|$ is $|x_{n} + L|$ which is bounded and hence $|x_{n}^{2} - L^{2}|$ is small when $|x_{n} - L|$ is small and vice versa. You will need to make this more formal by adding $\epsilon$'s.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show if $\lim x_n=L$ then $\lim x_n^2=L^2$ using the delta epsilon definition of limits.

$\lim x_n=L$ implies for any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that

$|x_n-L|<\varepsilon $ for all $n>N$

Note $L-\varepsilon < x_n<L+\varepsilon$ so $2L-\varepsilon < x_n+L<2L+\varepsilon$, for all $n>N$.

Then

$|x_n^2-L^2|=|(x_n+L)(x_n-L)|<|x_n+L||x_n-L|<(2L+\varepsilon )\varepsilon < \varepsilon^{\prime}$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: Since $x_{n} \geq 0$, we have $L \geq 0$ and your proof works because $L \geq 0$. However the conclusion holds true ($\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = L \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n}^{2} = L^{2}$) without this assumption. It would be better to use $||x_{n}| - |L|| \leq |x_{n} - L| < \epsilon$ to get $|x_{n}| < |L| + \epsilon$ and then $|x_{n} + L| \leq |x_{n}| + |L| < 2|L| + \epsilon$ to take care of any sign of $L$ and $x_{n}$.